# Which is the best way to make a MATLAB ga function that calls the simulation software and has access to the result?

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I created a simple genetic algorithm code using the
MATLAB genetic algorithm application optimtool.

#### Main:

```
function [x, fval, exitFlag, Output, population, SCORE] = main()
nVar = 1; FF = @opt;
k = 1;
opts = gaoptimset;
opts = gaoptimset(opts,'InitialPopulation',k,'PopulationSize',1);
[x, fval, exitFlag, Output, population, SCORE] = ga(FF,nVar,opts);
```

#### Objective function:

```
function [y] = opt(t)
y = abs( t - 1 );
```

I observe that ga runs well when I manipulate an objective function as a simple equation. In each iteration Ι expect that the variable `t` of the objective function is assigned to the value of individual `k` of the population. *But I mention that this assignment happens automatically.*

My final purpose is to use this simple problem inserting a command which calls a simulation software before the equation `y = abs( t - 1 )`. This software reads the individuals of the population `k` as input and outputs the variable `r`. Variable `t` of the equation `y = abs( t - 1 )` is assigned to `r`.

#### Question:

I would like ga to let me make my simulation software to read the value of `k`
manually as this happened in the previous example *automatically* (t <-- k).
Is this feasible using the ga application? Is there any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by using an external function that uses system calls to run your simulation software and manipulate it's output.

for example:

```
ga(@(x1)my_external_obj_fn(x1,param1,param2,...),nelements, nvars,A,b,[],[],LB,UB,@my_nonlcon_fn,@my_IntCon_fn,options)
...
```

and in your `output = my_external_obj_fn`

```
...
sim_fx = sprintf('your_sim_exec param1 param2... %s > outputfile');
system(sim_fx);

getoutput = sprintf('grep outputfile | sed > out_fitness')
system(getoutput)

fID = fopen(getoutput)
if fID ~= -1
output = textscan(fopen(fx2), '%s');
output = str2double(output)
...
```

Hope this helps